# twitter bootstrap 3 modal as non modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Is there a way to make bootstrap modal dialog non modal?

I'm using angular bootstrap with `backdrop: false`, but popup is modal even though backdrop is transparent. I cannot use controls that are under that popup.

In [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/qbm7cm48/13/), I wan't to be able  to use change text in input while popup is visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to override the CSS for the `modal` and `modal-dialog` classes; `.modal` still has a backdrop-like effect with the TRBL 0000 set:

```
.modal {
  top: initial;
  right: initial;
  bottom: initial;
  left: initial;
  width:100%;
  /* Looks same, but now you can click. See with: */
  top:20px;
}

.modal-dialog {
  margin:0;
}
```

Be aware that you won't be able to click underneath `.modal-dialog`'s margins, so best do your positioning in `.modal`. Sorry I don't have a cleaner solution, hopefully knowing the cause will help (maybe adjusting the height and width in JS in a callback would be nicer).

Forked Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stsod93a

Comment: added sample on jsfiddle to demo it

Comment: This solution seems to remove the shadow of the modal.